# find method in enzyme does not return a single node though I search for an element with unique id

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am new to reactjs and just trying to write a unit test for a simple component. 
I am using enzyme and expectjs for this purpose. 
Here is my component:

```
import  React from "react";

export class Panel extends  React.Component{
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="row panel">
            <div  className="col-sm-12 header">{this.props.children}-------Hi {this.props.uName}</div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 body"><img className="img-responsive" src={this.props.imgUrl} alt = "" /></div>
            <div id="enzymeTest" className="col-sm-12 footer">{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

Ant here is a test I wrote for it.

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect.js';
 import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
 import {T as p} from "../../src/app/components/T";
 import ToDoItem from "../../src/app/components/ToDoItem";

 describe('<P />', () => {
    it('renders without exploding', () => {

    const item = mockItem();
    const wrapper = shallow(<p attach={ true } />);
    expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('#enzymeTest').text()).to.equal('Hello');
   });
});
```

As you can see I am  just trying to test the text of the element but I get the following error:

```
1 failing

 1) <P /> renders without exploding:
 Error: Method âtextâ is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found inst           ead.
    at ShallowWrapper.single     (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:1436:17)
at ShallowWrapper.text    (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:715:21)
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:/tj/reactjs-basics/test/components/test.js:17:44              )
```

but I just have one element with id of enzymeTest. So a single node should be returned by find method and I do not understand why it throws this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: try change the name of component from p to Panel... I think react is messing with p tag

Comment: @LucasKatayama thanks but still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran here ... It really is the p problem..

If I ran this code

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect.js';
 import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';


class p extends  React.Component{
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="row panel">
            <div  className="col-sm-12 header">{this.props.children}-------Hi {this.props.uName}</div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 body"><img className="img-responsive" src={this.props.imgUrl} alt = "" /></div>
            <div id="enzymeTest" className="col-sm-12 footer">{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}

 describe('<P />', () => {
    it('renders without exploding', () => {

    const wrapper = shallow(<p attach={ true } >akjsbdjabsdkj</p>);
    expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
    console.log(wrapper);
    expect(wrapper.find('#enzymeTest').text()).to.equal('Hello');
   });
});
```

It gives

```
● <P /> › renders without exploding

    Method “text” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1436:17)
      at ShallowWrapper.text (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:715:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/test.js:26:85)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

But If you change the class name to

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect.js';
 import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';


class Panel extends  React.Component{
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="row panel">
            <div  className="col-sm-12 header">{this.props.children}-------Hi {this.props.uName}</div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 body"><img className="img-responsive" src={this.props.imgUrl} alt = "" /></div>
            <div id="enzymeTest" className="col-sm-12 footer">{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}

 describe('<P />', () => {
    it('renders without exploding', () => {

    const wrapper = shallow(<Panel attach={ true } >akjsbdjabsdkj</Panel>);
    expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
    console.log(wrapper);
    expect(wrapper.find('#enzymeTest').text()).to.equal('Hello');
   });
});
```

It works...

```
 FAIL  __tests__/test.js
  ● <P /> › renders without exploding

    expected 'akjsbdjabsdkj' to equal 'Hello'

      at Assertion.Object.<anonymous>.Assertion.assert (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:96:13)
      at Assertion.Object.<anonymous>.Assertion.be.Assertion.equal (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:216:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/test.js:25:96)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks a lot.   The only note for those who may see this post later on, apparently react does not like lower case naming so as soon as I change my component name to P or Panel my code starts working:

Comment: yeah you are right .. read this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized and it says that react thinks it is a p html tag